# Any way to set window bigger than desktop with Autohotkey?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I'm trying to solve this problem on Windows 7.

I need to set the window size bigger than actual size of desktop, so I can hide title bar and main menu of arbitrary application. Unfortunatelly it doesn't seem possible to set the window size bigger than the size of the desktop.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with AHK. It says about WinMove: "If Width and Height are large, most windows will go no larger than approximately 12 pixels beyond the dimensions of the desktop."

However, here is a similar thread with interesting suggestions: [Windows program to remove titlebar, frame, etc from a window?](https://superuser.com/questions/38687/windows-program-to-remove-titlebar-frame-etc-from-a-window)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021, `WinMove` is still subject to "dimensions of the desktop" (same with [AHK v2](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)). However, I managed to increase such "dimension" by adding a cheap *virtual display adapter*: these adapters comes in various connection standards, and does not seem to put too much pressure on GPU.

In [an old post on AHK forum](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98043-seeking-workaround-for-winmove-size-limitation/), DrHow also suggested `MouseClickDrag`. It automates the action of dragging and resizing the window by hand.