# Is there an application that removes the title bar of other applications?

Tags: windows, title-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows program to remove titlebar, frame, etc from a window?](https://superuser.com/questions/38687/windows-program-to-remove-titlebar-frame-etc-from-a-window)

I am wondering if there is a software, that does this? Either allowing to launch the program in full screen without the titlebar or moving it after it's launched, and allowing me to manually set the application to fullscreen.

Or perhaps I should try to write this myself if there is a win32 call to do this or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the scripting software http://www.autohotkey.com/
specifically this command:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm

You could use the command to resize the window, then 'hide' the titlebar.  There are examples in the documentation to show how to do this.