# How to remove/hide title bar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

This was possible in XP and Windows 7 (see [Is it possible to remove/hide Windows title bars?](https://superuser.com/questions/664559/is-it-possible-to-remove-hide-windows-title-bars)) - but I haven't been able to find the settings in Windows 10.  Is this still possible?  Thanks.

Comment: As with the issue referenced above, I'm interested in hiding or removing the title bar for all applications at once - e.g. Webstorm, LibreOffice, Office, etc.

Comment: Or how to add it back...

Answer (score 9):

Given that the answer provided in the linked question still had issues (didn't work in Vista - follow up suggestion reduced taskbar icons), I don't believe there's much hope for a suitable function within Win 10.

However, the comment provided by Mokubai suggesting to use Autohotkey may still be applicable here.

The following code in AHK will remove the Title Bar for the active window.

```
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
```

Comment: Although now that I've tested, it looks like that doesn't remove Windows Explorer title bar; just removes the top-right buttons :/

Comment: Wow, very useful, thank you! This also magically made it so that when I maximize said window, it goes completely fullscreen (above taskbar and everything, borders disappear) which is a highly desirable behavior for me! :)

Comment: `WinSet, Style, ^0xC00000, A` is better because you can toggle it back again when you want, or if you did it to the wrong window.

Comment: So... Instead of referencing some comment which seems to no longer exist, can someone update this with a full answer?

Answer (score 2):

Note that this also corresponds to Tablet mode vs. Desktop mode (Windows 10). I've discovered that in Tablet mode, it auto-hides the title bar unless you put your mouse at the top.

As for me personally, I find this extremely obnoxious, even if I'm using the touch screen, so I put it in Desktop mode.

To switch, click the icon at the bottom right of Windows 10 (where you set e.g. brightness, airplane mode, network settings, etc.). By default, you may have Tablet mode as one of your primary options; if not, click on Expand. (https://dottech.org/174526/how-to-switch-between-tablet-and-desktop-mode-in-windows-10-tip/)

To switch the default mode when you log in, go to the Windows 10 Settings app, click System => Tablet mode. It's straightforward from there.

Answer (score 1):

mostly by **pressing F11** will work for most of the stuff i guess ( for example it works with windows explorer, chrome, etc) and if not then try **Alt + Enter**, anyway there will be some stubborn software who no matter what you do won't allow us to hide the title bar. Enjoy

Comment: The question is how to remove/hide title bar. Going full screen will do that, but it's like setting your garden on fire to get rid of the weeds.

Comment: @Scott You don't set your garden on fire?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more up-to-date answer that uses AutoHotKey v2 to remove the Title Bar for the active window.

I'm using Windows 11 with PowerToys' FancyZones on two stacked 32" monitors. I wanted to hide the title bar in the Plex app because I have Plex running in the top right quadrant of the top monitor. This script allows the elements to be toggled.

```
;#HotIf WinActive("Plex")
;This is the shortcut key for ALT+Q
!q::
{
    WinSetStyle "^0xC00000", "A" ;Used for the caption  
    WinSetStyle "^0x40000", "A" ;Used for the sizebox
    WinSetStyle "^0x800000", "A" ;Used for the border
    WinMove 1279, -1436, 1281, 697, "A" ;Moves and resizes window
}
```

The HotIf allows the script to run only if the defined window is active. Here, it is commented out but I wanted to show how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what he's looking for? right
This is autohotkey script that hides titlebar of every window

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; Uncomment this if you want a hotkey to set it for every
; !+r::GoSub, AdjustAllWindows

; Initalise the hook
GoSub, HookWindow
; Run it once for every window
GoSub, AdjustAllWindows
Return

HookWindow:
    ; New Window Hook
    Gui +LastFound
    hWnd := WinExist()

    DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,hWnd )
    MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
    OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )

    ShellMessage(wParam,lParam) {
        If (wParam = 1) ;  HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED := 1
        {
            Sleep, 10
            AdjustWindow(lParam)
        }
    }
Return

; Adjust Window
AdjustWindow(id)
{
    WinId := id
    WinTitle := id = "A" ? "A" : "ahk_id " . id

    ; Uncomment this and comment the above if you don't want it to work on every window
    WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, %WinTitle%
}

AdjustAllWindows:
    WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
    Loop, %id%
    {
        AdjustWindow(id%A_Index%)
    }
Return
```

Answer (score -1):

there is some tips:

Step 1 : Login to your Windows 10 PC(Which is Primitive Step)

Step 2 : Open File Explorer or Press Windows + E or Open This PC

[See : How to Create Shortcut for My computer(This PC) in Windows 10]

Step 3 : Click on File tab,Which is on top of the tab.

Step 4 : Select Change Folder and Search Options / Options.
Step 5 : Select View tab.

Step 6 : Click on File and Folders.

Step 7 : Find the Option, Display the Full Path in title Bar.

Comment: Thanks for the response - but not exactly what I'm talking about.  This shows or hides the full path for folders in the Title Bar when navigating through Windows Explorer.  I'd like to hide the Title Bar for all applications where it isn't required.