# How do I remove the bar with close/minimize/maximize/app_name in all windows, because I just use keyboard shortcuts to perform these actions?

Tags: windows, windows-10

As in the topic. I don't like wasting space. I run all apps that I can in full screen mode + extensions such as https://github.com/tridactyl/tridactyl , but still there's plenty of software where the window bar is visible and takes space.

Windows 10.

Under Linux I used and enjoyed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwm

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/1262225/how-to-remove-hide-title-bar-in-windows-10/1598769) .. Short answer, you don't.  Just like you couldn't do this with Gnome or KDE (probably).. Windows only offers a single window manager.. thats just how it works.  Hopefully someone will come in here a prove me wrong but I doubt it.  On windows, developers also extend the titlebar to do whatever they want.  This is a bad idea (on windows that is).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/hide title bar in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1262225/how-to-remove-hide-title-bar-in-windows-10)

Comment: You can try to make the title bat height smaller: https://superuser.com/questions/461982/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows-8