# Is it possible to disable the title bar on metro apps in Windows 8.1 Update?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, gui, modern-ui

I find the title bar a bit annoying when using the mouse in Internet Explorer. Many website have their navigation at the top, after all.

Comment: No; There is no way to disable the title bar at this time on Modern UI applications;  You could in theory make Windows think you have a touch screen, if you do that, it won't be shown.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the info! (If you submit it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.)

Answer (score 4):

You could press the SHIFT key to hide the title bar once it appeared to lower this annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**ModernMix's**](http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/) setting (under Advanced) "Hide Windows 8.1 Update 1 fullscreen app titlebar".

#### Side effects to installing ModernMix:

- By default, ModernMix makes some other tweaks related to running Metro apps in Desktop windows, which you can change in General
- App previews in the <kbd>Win + Tab</kbd> sidebar seem worse (totally black, etc.)
- Switching apps through <kbd>Win + Tab</kbd> doesn't have animations

ModernMix has a (free) 30-day evaluation trial and costs $5 for unlimited use.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. [ModernMix](http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/) is commercial ($4.99), and this should be clearly stated in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and script:

```
;-Caption
LWIN & LButton::
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
return
;

;+Caption
LWIN & RButton::
WinSet, Style, +0xC00000, A
return
;
```

Please consult this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/38687/windows-program-to-remove-titlebar-frame-etc-from-a-window) for more info, there has been a question like this one

Comment: This script has nothing to do with the modern ui title bar and would not work.