# How to always show the apps title bar in windows 8.1 update?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8-apps

Well, the title says it all. I am running Windows 8.1 Update 1 which came out in April. It introduces title bars to apps with a close-button like in desktop-programs. Can I make the title bar to appear at all times?

Comment: What sort of device are we talking about?  The title bar is displayed on devices with touch displays.  There is no way to enable/disable the title bar at this time.

Comment: Opposite request: http://superuser.com/questions/743349/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-title-bar-on-metro-apps-in-windows-8-1-update

Comment: for me, the title bar appears when i move the mouse at the top of the app on a no-touch-device (dell notebook), so i assume it doesn't depend on the device?

Answer (score 0):

It's $5 but install ModernMix from http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/

I have done it and found that if you run the settings (just type ModernMix after install) and  uncheck "Overlay in the top right corner" it just adds the bar with the 3 standard buttons to all your Metro apps with no other mess. If you have an app or two that need to be full screen just go in ModernMix Settings for "App Settings" and right click on the App and force fullscreen for those.