# Is there a way to get rid of window frames?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, desktop

I don't need a general solution, I just want to get rid of the window frame for PowerShell. For example, this is how my desktop looks now:

[image]

And here is what I ideally want:

[image]

But under the case that this is impossible, I'll settle for

[image]

I assume this will require some pretty funky registry edits or something, or maybe a third-party powershell client. I'm fine with either. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you modify `powershell.exe` to this behavior, no, you can integrate power shell console in your own console application where you have complete control over the GUI.

Comment: How easy would it be to write a console app? I have a lot of programming experience but I never though of this

Comment: Only way to find out is to try

Comment: Now now, let's not jump to "make it yourself" yet. See this: http://superuser.com/questions/38687/windows-program-to-remove-titlebar-frame-etc-from-a-window for an AHK script that may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu). In particular experiment with these settings:

- Appearance / Hide caption always
- Appearance / Scrollbar
- Appearance / Frame width
- Tab bar / Don't show
- Status bar / Show status bar (off)

The screenshot below is what I managed to do. Ignore the icon at the upper right; that is from something else.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but I doubt this will start at startup and have the changes persist, correct? Also, does it provide functionality to be able to move a window despite having no title bar?

Comment: @jphollowed, this is not the powershell.exe console. It is its own thing. Yes, its settings will persist. I don't know about moving. You might have to leave the title bar or tab bar on. Anyway, you can experiment yourself.

Comment: Well I've tried it out and I quite like it, but I turned off the title bar and everything and now I cannot get back to the settings or move the window or anything! Would you happen to know some shortcuts to open the menus?

Comment: @jphollowed, the keyboard shortcuts are [here](http://conemu.github.io/en/KeyboardShortcuts.html). Main web site [here](http://conemu.github.io/). Win+Alt+P to show the settings. You can drag the window with Ctrl+Alt+LeftMouseButton.

Comment: @dangh thank you very much, I've got it all set up, this is perfect

Comment: @jphollowed, okay, great :) Please upvote this answer and select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

for those who have not found a solution yet ,

in your .bat script / cmd environment, you can use an external function called nircmd which includes a whole lot of other features like transparency etc,& Can be called by  :

```
title hello world
nircmd.exe win -style title "hello world" 0x00C00000
```

nircmd can be downloaded from *http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html*

Answer (score 0):

For those of you familiar with AutoHotKey, here's the script I used to achieve precisely the same effect as the first screenshot:

```
;Hide borders, title bar, menu bar and vertical scroll
LWin & LButton::
WinSet, Style, -0xC40000, A
WinSet, Style, +0x40000000, A
WinSet, Style, +0x80000000, A
WinSet, Style, -0x200000, A
Return

;Show borders, title bar, menu bar and vertical scroll
LWin & RButton::
WinSet, Style, +0xC40000, A
WinSet, Style, -0x40000000, A
WinSet, Style, -0x80000000, A
WinSet, Style, +0x200000, A
Return
```