# VMWare Workstation 12 Player remove the toolbar in windowed mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to remove the menu/tool/status bar in windowed mode? The bar containing the `Player` menu, pause button, full screen and the audio, network, disk etc. status icons on the right.

[image]

I am asking about the bar immediately under the Windows title bar which contains the program icon, title and the minimize, maximize and close buttons <- I would like to hide this one also, but not a VMWare question.

I am assuming there might be some setting for it that can be set in the configuration file, as in this example: https://superuser.com/a/559146/90320

**Update**

I managed to hide the window title bar using: https://superuser.com/a/215707/90320

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the file

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini
```

Add the line:

```
pref.allowHideControls = "TRUE"
```

Close and reopen VMWare Workstation. Then right click on the title bar and you will see the option to hide controls.

This is confirmed working for me in Workstation 12 and 14.

Comment: According to the VMWare [knowledge base article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2013763), there is more to this solution, then just adding that line to the preferences.ini file.  In addition, the location you indicate does appear to be correct.

Comment: This works, but note that you have to open the VMWare *Workstation* (`vmware.exe`), not the *Player* (`vmplayer.exe`). Tested on VMWare Workstation Pro 14.

Answer (score 0):

As of VMware Workstation Player 14.0 (and this is true for earlier versions as well), there is no configuration option to hide the Player menu/toolbar. (I know it's hard to prove a negative, but you'll either have to trust me on this or run `strings` on all of the binaries included with VMware Player, filter it by strings that start with `pref.`, look for ones that sound relevant, try all of those, and observe that none of them do what you want.)

If you want to run VMs with no UI at all, then you perhaps could consider [`vmware-kvm.exe`](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/03/whats-cool-vmware-kvm-utility.html) (which is included with Player), but it always runs VMs in full screen mode.