# Display PDF with no interface

Tags: windows, pdf

Is there a way to display PDF pages without any interface under win10? Currently every app that I found had some menu at the top. What I want is to simply display pages as they are, zoom and search by shortcut or in a hidden bar. I want the page of the document to take all available height, in windowed mode.

Comment: Being in windowed mode is probably the limiting factor. Most pdf readers will reduce or eliminate their user interface in fullscreen mode, but that's usually unnecessary in windowed mode. Is there a specific reason why you can't use fullscreen mode in like... adobe acrobat reader?

Answer (score 1):

A key phrase that is useful in searches is "distraction free". This phrase arose in the world of text editors for people looking for minimal user interface.

For example, a search for "distraction free PDF viewer" yielded

> SumatraPDF is an easy to use free PDF reader for Windows. While it is easy and simple to work with, it's also open for heavy customization if you so choose. Different types of viewing modes are available, like Single Page, Facing, Book View, and Presentation. The latter view is great for distraction-free reading

In a spirit of curiosity I installed it and adjusted its settings, using Advanced settings to set menu display off.

I didn't wantto change my default PDF viewer so, to test the initial view on starting the viewer, I  used the context menu of Windows explorer (file manager) on a PDF file to "Open with" SumatraPDF. It's initial appearance was this:

[image: Sumatra PDF]

You can also toggle the presence of the menu bar using F9.

I suspect the only built-in way to eliminate the remaining window decoration (title bar and scroll bar) is to use presentation mode (F5) which is full-screen.

However see

- [Windows program to remove titlebar, frame, etc from a window?](https://superuser.com/q/38687/52492)

Answer (score 0):

SumatraPDF or MuPDF or Edge when windowed only need a Windows System Title bar, but same as MS Edge (on Left and unsure if it can remove scrollbars), Windows Apps can not hide that Title Bar themselves other than go fullscreen (`F` key in SumatraPDF)

[image]

**To set MS Edge to "Distraction Free"

place a Drag'N'drop shortcut or SendTo with  the command**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="%~dpn1.pdf#toolbar=0"
```

If you **do** want the AutoHide toolbar then set that last `0` to `1`

[image]